# Pandas Sorting with condition

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, conditional-formatting

Suppose I have following dataframe:

| price | position | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 1 | 2023-01-08 |
| 30 | 4 | 2023-01-08 |
| 140 | 2 | 2023-01-09 |
| 140 | 3 | 2023-01-09 |
| 50 | 1 | 2023-01-09 |
| 50 | 4 | 2023-01-09 |
| 260 | 2 | 2023-01-09 |
| 260 | 3 | 2023-01-09 |

The dataframe has both 'position' and 'datetime' in ascending order.

I want specific values in 'position' ( 1 and 4) to be sorted in descending order within the same 'datetime' values to have the end result as following:

| price | position | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 4 | 2023-01-08 |
| 30 | 1 | 2023-01-08 |
| 140 | 2 | 2023-01-09 |
| 140 | 3 | 2023-01-09 |
| 50 | 4 | 2023-01-09 |
| 50 | 1 | 2023-01-09 |
| 260 | 2 | 2023-01-09 |
| 260 | 3 | 2023-01-09 |

I tried this code

```
df_trade = df_trade[df_trade.position == 4 or df_trade.position == 1].sort_values(by = ["position"], ascending = False)
```

but it gives

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I guess there must be better, easy ways.

Comment: Don't use `or` between to series conditions, use `|`: `df_trade.position.eq(4) | df_trade.position.eq(1)`. You can also use `isin`: `df_trade.isin([1,4])`. This would fix the ValueError. But there are more logic in your question than just that.

Comment: @QuangHoang when I use df_trade = df_trade[df_trade.position.eq(4) | df_trade.position.eq(1)].sort_values(by = ["position"], ascending = False) I get new dataframe without position == 2 or position == 3, and 'datetime' column is also sorted with all position  == 4 on the top and position == 1 on the bottom

Comment: @QuangHoang df_trade = df_trade[df_trade.position.eq(4) | df_trade.position.eq(1)].sort_values(by = ["datetime", "position"], ascending = [True, False]) By using this code I get new data frame with position == 4 and position == 1 well sorted, but this data frame is without those of position == 2 and position == 3

Comment: I imagine the dates for price 140 might rather be "2023-01-08"?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) with the "position" Series in which you use the negative values of 1/4:

```
import numpy as np

order = np.lexsort([df['position'].mul(np.where(df['position'].isin([1,4]), -1, 1)), df['datetime']])

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Pandas equivalent:

```
(df.assign(key=df['position'].mul(np.where(df['position'].isin([1,4]), -1, 1)))
   .sort_values(by=['datetime', 'key'])
   .drop(columns='key')
 )
```

Output:

```
   price  position    datetime
1     30         4  2023-01-08
0     30         1  2023-01-08
5     50         4  2023-01-09
4     50         1  2023-01-09
2    140         2  2023-01-09
6    260         2  2023-01-09
3    140         3  2023-01-09
7    260         3  2023-01-09
```

Comment: This one works!